# Using trace file in NS-3

Tags: networking, network-programming, ns-3

I want to know how to use your own video trace in an example given in ns-3 examples folder.

Do I need to make change in just this line of the code?

UdpTraceClientHelper client(server address,port, "url address to that video trace")

I am looking for video traces from this site:

http://trace.eas.asu.edu/mpeg4/single/SonyCIF_G16B1Mp/SonyCIF_G16B1Mp01/

In the url address, I am using the address of the verbose trace file. Is that the right approach?

When I do this, it is still making use of the default hard coded file as a trace file.

In short, I want to know how to use a video trace file in ns3 ?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, you download the file and save it to a location in your project (you may replace the "default hard coded file" as you named it) ;)